# Creating a Textbox dynamically in for loop

Tags: asp.net

I was trying to create a table dynamically and put textboxes in it. Here in the following code, i was trying to create a textbox  with a distinct name for each k. But only the last value of k is getting displayed in the textbox. I was wondering how i could give a name to Textbox so all are shown.

```
for (int k = 0; k < tblCols; k++)
{
    TableCell tc = new TableCell(); 
    TextBox txtCompanyName = new TextBox();
    txtCompanyName.Text = dsmissing.Tables[0].Rows[tblCols- 1]["NewCompanyName"].ToString();
tc.Controls.Add(txtCompanyName);
}
```

Comment: You tried `txtCompanyName.Name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line

```
dsmissing.Tables[0].Rows[tblCols- 1]["NewCompanyName"].ToString();
```

With

```
dsmissing.Tables[0].Rows[k]["NewCompanyName"].ToString();
```

I assume you are talking about ID like below.

```
for (int k = 0; k < tblCols; k++)
{
    TableCell tc = new TableCell(); 
    TextBox txtCompanyName = new TextBox();
    txtCompanyName.Text = dsmissing.Tables[0].Rows[k]["NewCompanyName"].ToString();
    txtCompanyName.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
    tc.Controls.Add(txtCompanyName);
}
```

Comment: txtCompanyName will have dsmissing.Tables[0].Rows[k]["NewCompanyName"].ToString() value. I want to give a different name for each textbox in the for loop

Comment: You mean to say ID ? textbox.ID ?

Comment: Right. Sorry i dint know you call it as ID. i wanted txtCompanyName1, txtCompanyName2,.... for each textbox..

Comment: Fantastic. This works! But, is there a way i can ID a textbox with something i want. Just curious :-)

Comment: When i use Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") it gives me random uniqueID. What if i want an ID of my choice.. like txtbox1 as ID. Do i make any sense? Thank you Pankaj for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have meant to do this:

```
for (int k = 0; k < tblCols; k++)
{
    TableCell tc = new TableCell(); 
    TextBox txtCompanyName = new TextBox();
    //txtCompanyName.Text = dsmissing.Tables[0].Rows[tblCols-1 ["NewCompanyName"].ToString();
    txtCompanyName.Text = dsmissing.Tables[0].Rows[k]["NewCompanyName"].ToString();
    tc.Controls.Add(txtCompanyName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Surely this will work and it is easy to understand**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1();
}
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.ID = "lbl_label";
        lbl.Text = "Enter the values";
        form1.Controls.Add(lbl);
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.ID = "tbx_textbox";
        form1.Controls.Add(tb);
        Button bt = new Button();
        bt.ID = "bt_button";
        bt.Text = "click";
        form1.Controls.Add(bt);

    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
}
public void button1()
{
    Table table = new Table();
    TableRow row = null;
    TableCell cell = null;
    TextBox tbx1 = this.Page.FindControl("tbx_textbox") as TextBox;
    try
    {
        int a = int.Parse(tbx1.Text);
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        {
            row = new TableRow();
            cell = new TableCell();
            TextBox tx = new TextBox();
            tx.ID = "box" + i.ToString();
            cell.Controls.Add(tx);
            row.Cells.Add(cell);
            table.Rows.Add(row);
            form1.Controls.Add(table);
        }
        }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
    finally
    {
        table = null;
    }
}
```